# AngularJS returned 404 if HTML5 URL is typed by user, works OK if redirects to the same view within

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have the following code:

```
app.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    // use the HTML5 History API
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider.
        when('/jamView', {
            templateUrl: 'app/jam/jam.view.html',
            controller: 'JamCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/jamView'
        });
}]);
```

...and

```
$scope.jamActionSelected = function(action) {

    switch(action) {
        case 'Find':
            $location.path('/jamView');
            break;
        default:
            $location.path('/jamView');
    }
}
```

When the browser is redirected to the view **/jamView** by **$scope.jamActionSelected** the page loads fine and the URL becomes **localhost:3000/jamView** as it should be. However, if I try to reload the page with that URL I get **"Not found 404"**. I thought that regardless of whether the browser was redirected to a view by a function or by typing in the URL it should work the same way. However, it seems like it is able to resolve the view from within (invoked by function), but not if the user wants to go to that view by typing that URL. Why is it happening and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: There are plenty of articles on this issue on the site, and a very good article written by the folks that developed ui-router. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode. Essentially, you need to enable URL Rewrites on your server, whatever server that might be.  This is also mentioned in some detail in the angular documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#!/

Comment: This is specifically being caused by using `html5Mode(true)` without having the server set up to support html5Mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing related to AngularJS, and must be done server-side.

The fact is that when you use the HTML5 History API, it only simulates that you're navigating to another URL, but in fact, you are in the same URL, but with the `location` and `history` changed.

When you type the URL into the bar, the browser sends that information to the server, and the latter respond with the respective content.

If using Node.js, for example, you can install the `connect-history-api-fallback` package, to make all your URLs to send the same content, and then AngularJS will be able to work with that content.

If using ASP.NET MVC, you can create one single `Route` to map all your requests, for example:

```
context.MapRoute(
  name: "SPARouting",
  url: "{*.}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Application", action = "Index" }
);
```

And you can do the same with other server technologies. To find about yours, just google for it, e.g:

> Using HTML5 History API with [your server technology goes here].

Or you can take a look at [this tutorial](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode), suggested by [@Claies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2495283/claies), that shows several different examples.